# Как использовать пространство имен (xmlns) лишь для определенного класса?

Tags: xml, namespace, jaxb

У меня есть два класса: A и B.

```
package a.b;
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "B")
public class B {
    private String pos;

    public B() {
    }

    public B(String pos) {
        this.pos = pos;
    }
}
```

Класс A:

```
package a;
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "A")
public class A {
    @XmlElement(name = "B")
    private B b;

    public A() {
    }

    public A(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

Аннотация для пакета:

```
@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(
    namespace = "http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05",
    elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED
)
package a.b;
```

Когда я создаю xml-объект из класса B, результат меня устраивает: я получаю

```
<B xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
    <pos>pos</pos>
</B>
```

Однако, если я создаю объект из класса A, то получаю

```
<A xmlns:ns2="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
    <B>
        <ns2:pos>pos</ns2:pos>
    </B>
</A>
```

Ожидаю:

```
<A>
    <B xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
        <pos>pos</pos>
    </B>
</A>
```

Как я могу получить ожидаемый результат?

PS: Для маршаллинга использую следующий код:

```
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(a.getClass());
    Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
    marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);

    marshaller.marshal(a, stringWriter);
    System.out.println(stringWriter.toString());
```

Comment: А для пакета `a` у Вас что в аннотации?

Comment: @lexicore ничего

Comment: Хм, странно. Непотяно, почему тогда `http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05` как пространство имён берётся.

Comment: @lexicore ничего странного. Это берется из пакета a.b

Comment: Да не должно, это же другой пакет. Попробуйте добавить `@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema(
    namespace = "",
    elementFormDefault = javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED
)` в пакет `a`.